# Función de envio de correo electronico en php no funciona

Tags: php, email

Buen día de nuevo :)
Me encuentro realizando una bolsa de trabajo, actualmente todo es funcional excepto la consulta que voy a hacer a continuación, lo único en lo que falla actualmente es en el envío de correos a las personas que se registran o bien quieren recuperar su contraseña, he investigado distintas formas de realizar esta tarea y dentro de lo que en mi conocimiento se encuentra aun no encuentro el error que cometí a continuación comparto los códigos, gracias de antemano estaré al pendiente por si necesito modificar la pregunta o bien contestar comentarios.

Dentro de una carpeta llamada lib inclui los archivos de conexion y herramientas en herramientas esta la funcion enviar correo que recibe los datos y realiza la tarea:

```
//funcion que envia un correo electronico
    function envio_correo($dir_email, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabecera){
       $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0/r/n";
       $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1/r/n";    
       $headers.= $cabecera."/r/n";
       return mail($dir_email, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabecera);
    }
```

Dentro del controlador tengo el archivo egresado_registro:

```
<?php 
    require_once("modelo/egresado.php");
    require_once("lib/herramientas.php");
    session_start();
    
    $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    $captcha = test_input($_POST['captcha']);
    
    /*if (!verificar_captcha($captcha)) {
        $_SESSION['msj'] = "El Captcha no coincide";
        exit(0);
    }*/
    
    if(buscar_x_email($email)){
            $_SESSION['msj'] = "Este correo ya se registro";
        }
        else {
            $egresado = Array(
                "nombre" => test_input($_POST['nombre']),
                "carrera" => test_input($_POST['carrera']),
                "email" => test_input($_POST['email']),
                "domicilio" => test_input($_POST['domicilio']),
                "telefono" => test_input($_POST['telefono']),
                "trabajo" => test_input($_POST['trabajo']),                
                "titulado" => ((test_input($_POST['titulado']) == si) ? 1 : 0),
                "generacion" => test_input($_POST['generacion']),
                "clave" => (rand(1000, 9999))
            );
            $asunto = "Envio de Nip Acceso Al Sistemas Bolsa de Trabajo UPRR";
            $cabecera = "From: <claradeasis_r@yahoo.com.mx>";
            $mensaje = "Regresa a la pagina principal y logeate con tu usuario y contraseña: ".$egresado['clave'];
            envio_correo($_POST['email'], $asunto, $mensaje, $cabecera);
            crear_egresado($egresado);
            $_SESSION['msj'] = "Revisa tu correo, y accede con tus datos";
            header("location: index.php");
            exit(0);
        }
?>
```

Eso con respecto a registrar un nuevo usuario, aqui el recuperar contraseña:

```
<?php 
require_once 'lib/herramientas.php';
if ($_GET['usuario'] == 1) {
    require_once 'modelo/egresado.php';
    $egresado = buscar_x_email($_POST['usuario']);
    if ($egresado) {
        $asunto = "Reestablecer clave de acceso Bolsa de Trabajo UPRR";
        $cabecera = "From: <claradeasis_r@yahoo.com.mx>";
        $mensaje = "Recuerda tu clave de acceso, para evitar ser dado de baja de la aplicacion".$egresado['clave'];
        envio_correo($egresado['email'], $asunto, $mensaje, $cabecera);
        $_SESSION['msj'] = "Se ha enviado tu clave de acceso a tu correo";
        header("location: index.php");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['msj'] = "El correo ingresado no se encontro en la base de datos";
        header("location: index.php");
        exit(0);
    }
}
if ($_GET['usuario'] == 2) {
    require_once 'modelo/empresa.php';
    $empresa = buscar_x_rfc($_POST['usuario']);
    if ($empresa) {
        $asunto = "Reestablecer clave de acceso Bolsa de Trabajo UPRR";
        $cabecera = "From: <claradeasis_r@yahoo.com.mx>";
        $mensaje = "Recuerda tu clave de acceso".$empresa['clave'];
        envio_correo($empresa['email'], $asunto, $mensaje, $cabecera); 
        $_SESSION['msj'] = "Se ha enviado tu clave de acceso a tu correo";
        header("location: index.php");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['msj'] = "El RFC ingresado no se encontro en la base de datos";
        header("location: index.php");
        exit(0);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Es altamente recomendado usar [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), es multiplataforma y sencillo de implementar. No necesitas usar composer para instalarlo, solo el directorio `src`. También hay bastantes consultas al respecto en [el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+phpmailer). El problema con la función `mail()` integrada es que solo trabaja bien en Windows, en hostings (usualmente linux) es [más complicado](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-notes) hacerla funcionar.